# how do i use brevo api to send whatsapp messages?

Tags: javascript, next.js, whatsapp, brevo

following these docs https://mukulsib.readme.io/reference/sendwhatsappmessage

i wrote this code:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const API_KEY = '/i got api key from brevo SMTP & API page/';

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  if (req.method === 'POST') {
    const { phoneNumbers, Message } = req.body;

    for (const phone of phoneNumbers) {
        const options = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
              accept: 'application/json',
              'content-type': 'application/json',
              'api-key': API_KEY,
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                senderNumber: '123456789', 
                text: Message, 
                contactNumbers: [phone,]
            })
        };

            try {
                const response = await axios.request(options);
                console.log(`Message sent successfully to ${phone}`);
                console.log('Response data:', response.data);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(`Error sending message to ${phone}:`, error.message);
            }
        }
    
            res.status(200).json({ message: 'Messages sent' });
        } else {
            res.status(405).json({ error: 'Method not allowed' });
        }
    }
```

and when i try it on the docs page i get this error:
{"code": "permission_denied", "message": "Your account is not registered"}

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an issue with your API key. It might not be the correct one or the validity might be over. Can you regenerate the key again and try. Also, logging the proper formatted error in catch can help you find the issue, if it is anything other than API key (authorization issue)

Comment: just tried that same error sending message: Request failed with status code 403
Detailed error: {
  code: 'permission_denied',
  message: 'Your account is not registered'
}

Comment: { code: 'permission_denied', message: 'Your account is not registered' }
The JSON response very clearly states that your account is not registered. If it helps, can you create another user login and generate API_KEY for the same. 
403 means `access to the requested resource is forbidden`, so it is most definitely, you dont have permission or appropriate key to run the app

Comment: Yeah i figured, I've already contacted brevo support team and i'm waiting on their answer

Comment: Sure, let us know the further progress